# Where is the screen shot (aka grabber or grab) app?

Tags: utilities, screen-capture, macos

I haven't used my Mac in a while (I'm a Ubuntu user).

Where is that grabber app?  I don;'t see it under applications or settings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On my machine (running 10.8.3), it is in `/Applications/Utilities/Grab.app`.

You can search for this using Spotlight: press <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd>  or click the magnifying glass near top right in the menu bar.

There are also some key shortcuts that save (or copy to the clipboard) images from the screen, clipped in various ways. <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> is one I use regularly, but there are several variants on this.

Answer (score 5):

- Command-Shift-3: Take a screenshot of the screen, and save it as a file on the desktop
- Command-Shift-4, then select an area: Take a screenshot of an area and save it as a file on the desktop
- Command-Shift-4, then space, then click a window: Take a screenshot of a window and save it as a file on the desktop
- Command-Control-Shift-3: Take a screenshot of the screen, and save it to the clipboard
- Command-Control-Shift-4, then select an area: Take a screenshot of an area and save it to the clipboard
- Command-Control-Shift-4, then space, then click a window: Take a screenshot of a window and save it to the clipboard

Answer (score 2):

Open up the launchpad (that rocket thing on the bottom left)

Go to Utilities

Then you will see Grab - which you can also drag down to your launcher bar for easier access!